# Converting real-life perspective photos into orthographic view for texture creation

Tags: textures, perspective

I'm struggling to find software that will enable me to take real life photos and make them "flat" (orthographic) for use in textures.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to take perspective photos and make them orthographic? The simpler it is the better. I've tried using Photoshop's adaptive wide angle filter with no luck.[image]
Here is an example photo. The perspective is obvious, because the straight lines (in real life) are not straight (in the photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIMP has a "Lens Distortion" filter under Filters / Distorts.

[image]

But clearly that is not the preferred option as it leads to data loss. There are cameras (cheap ones too) with lenses that don't produce such strong distortion.

Comment: The results there look really good. I'll try that with probably multiple photos